# Does $\star(\text{d}\omega)=0$ implies $\text{d}\omega=0$?

Tags: differential-forms, vector-fields

Yes, $\star(\text{d}\omega)$ is one definition to $\text{rot} \ v$. I need to prove that if $\text{rot} \ v=0$ then $v$ is locally exact (derives locally from a potential, more context can be provided [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4200282/v-is-locally-potential-iff-textd-omega-0-where-omega-u-leftv-u/4200809#4200809)). And yes, I've checked others answers, like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1393796/if-the-curl-of-some-vector-function-0-is-it-a-must-that-this-vector-function) (and I know how to solve this problem). But this came to my mind, because in this case, as a consequence, $\text{d}\omega = 0$. Is this true in general?

The definition I have for the Hodge Star Operation on a $k-$form of $\Bbb{R}^{n}$ is that
\begin{align*}
\star(d_{x_{i_{1}}} \wedge \dots \wedge d_{x_{i_{k}}}) = (-1)^{\text{sgn}\ \sigma} (d_{x_{j_{1}}} \wedge \dots \wedge d_{x_{j_{n-k}}}),\ \text{where} \ (i_{1}\dots i_{k}j_{i}\dots j_{n-k}) \in S_{n}.
\end{align*}
If the latter is $0$, then $d_{x_{j_{a}}}=d_{x_{j_{b}}}$ for some $a,b$. But all of $d_{x}$'s form a base for the dual of $k-$form of $\Bbb{R}^{n}$, so this can't happen. This is enough to conclude that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note $**=\pm id$

Comment: @ArcticChar Simple as that! I was kind blind for not to see this. Thanks!